# Complex SQL Server Pivot Involving Null and blank vs. Filled values

Tags: sql-server, null, pivot, grouping, blank-line

I need to separate the "dep" column into 2 different columns one being "recorded" the other being "unrecorded". the "unrecorded" column will contain the sum of time for entries where "dep" is blank or null for that day. The "recorded" column needs to display the sum of time for that day where the "dep" column is not null or blank.

So far this is what I have

```
 SELECT Cast(Start_Time AS DATE) AS Date, dep, 
 sum(time) as "Total Time"
 FROM A6K_Events
 Group By Cast(Start_Time AS DATE), dep
```

and it yields this

```
 +------------+--------------+------------+
 | Date       | Dep          | Total Time |
 +------------+--------------+------------+
 | 2018-06-29 | Null         | 3544       |
 +------------+--------------+------------+
 | 2018-06-29 | Other        | 268        |
 +------------+--------------+------------+
 | 2018-06-29 | Training     | 471        |
 +------------+--------------+------------+
 | 2018-06-29 | Change Point | 371        |
 +------------+--------------+------------+
 | 2018-06-28 | Null         | 4519       |
 +------------+--------------+------------+
 | 2018-06-28 | Training     | 1324       |
 +------------+--------------+------------+
 | 2018-06-28 |              | 50         |
 +------------+--------------+------------+
```

This is what I would like the end result to be

```
+------------+----------+------------+
| Date       | Recorded | Unrecorded |
+------------+----------+------------+
| 2018-06-29 | 1110     | 3544       |
+------------+----------+------------+
| 2018-06-28 | 1324     | 4569       |
+------------+----------+------------+
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. I cannot figure out how to pivot and filter out null and blank values into one column while the other filled values into another column.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot is not required, we can fetch the data using CASE statement

```
 SELECT start_time as Date, sum(case when dep is not NULL or dep <> '' then time end) as "Recorded", sum(case when dep is NULL or dep = '' then time end) as "Unrecorded"
 FROM A6K_Events
 Group By start_time order by 1 desc
```